# Displaying a picture to a record it was just uploaded to

Tags: lightning-web-components

I have created an LWC for a file uploader to upload pictures to a record, what I want to do next is display the photo that was just uploaded to that record automatically, Does anyone know how this is possible?
[image]

Here is the code for the image uploader:

HTML:

```
<template>
    <template if:false={removeUpload}>
        <lightning-file-upload
                label="Upload Book Cover"
                name="fileUploader"
                accept={acceptedFormats}
                record-id={myRecordId}
                onuploadfinished={handleUploadFinished}
                multiple>
        </lightning-file-upload>
    </template>
</template>
```

JavaScript:

```
import { LightningElement, api } from 'lwc';

export default class BookPicLWC extends LightningElement {

    @api
    myRecordId;
    removeUpload=false;

    get acceptedFormats() {
      return ['.pdf', '.png', '.jpg', '.jpeg'];
    }

    handleUploadFinished(event) {
        // Get the list of uploaded files
        const uploadedFiles = event.detail.files;
        alert("No. of files uploaded : " + uploadedFiles.length);
        this.removeUpload=true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

the documentation demonstrates how to implement `Links` to preview your files, but not how to display image previews by default (like, embedded image display)

[Use Open Files](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/use_open_files)

> The desktop file previewer offers image and SVG-based multi-page
> office documents preview, presentation mode, and quick access to file
> actions like share, download, upload, and delete.

There is also a user who has posted a [gist](https://gist.github.com/amitastreait/6d80c89ff95bb63bbd03659713e43d8d) on usage for preview/download which you can refer to

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

1. In .Js add a property linkOfUploadedFile
2. In handleUploadFinished(event) method, get the content version id

   this.linkOfUploadedFile  ='/sfc/servlet.shepherd/version/download/'+event.detail.files[0].contentVersionId;

3.Add img tag in .html file to show the image if linkOfUploadedFile is true and style it as per you need

```
<img lwc:if={linkOfUploadedFile} src={linkOfUploadedFile}>
```